# How to convert an XML schema (XSD) to Relax NG?

Tags: xsd, converters, relaxng

The [Relax NG homepage](http://relaxng.org/#conversion) lists the Sun RELAX NG Converter which apparently is able to convert an XSD file to a relaxng one - but the link is dead and a [blog entry about secondary sources](http://postneo.com/2007/01/16/all-i-want-to-do-is-convert-my-schema) seems to be outdated as well.

I am not interested in a web-based converter.

Btw, the XML schema I want to convert uses inheritance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Kohsuke Kawaguchi's Relax NG converter (aka the Sun Relax NG Converter) is currently available at http://java.net/projects/msv and http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cg%3A%22net.java.dev.msv%22 (thanks to KK for the information).

Answer (score 5):

The old Sun RELAX NG Converter is nowadays bundled with the (Sun) ['Multi-Schema Validator'](http://java.net/projects/msv) - msv. With that term you can search in your distributions package repository.

For example Fedora (e.g. 17) includes it.

### Install on Fedora

```
# yum install msv-rngconv msv-manual
```

### Usage on Fedora

```
$ rngconv my.xsd > my.rng
```

Test the result:

```
$ xmllint --relaxng my.rng --noout some.xml
```

Conversion to compact syntax:

```
$ trang -I rng -O rnc my.rng my.rnc
```

(trang is also available via the main Fedora package repository)

The other way (perhaps after adding stuff to the compact syntax file):

```
$ trang -I rnc -O rng my.rnc my.rng
```

Msv seems to be quite powerful - I tested it with a fairly sized xsd file that uses inheritance, extensive patterns and includes another xsd file.

Comment: Strangely trang on Debian Jessie does not seem to be able to convert from rng to rnc anymore.

Comment: @helcim, perhaps `trang` isn't free enough for Debian anymore :D. Just kidding, my trang examples contained a mixup in the order of input/output format options (`-I`/`-O`) it is now fixed. Perhaps this was the real issue for you?

Comment: I'm getting: 

   Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.thaiopensource.relaxng.parse.sax.SAXParseable.<init>(Ljavax/xml/transform/sax/SAXSource;Lcom/thaiopensource/resolver/xml/sax/SAXResolver;Lorg/xml/sax/ErrorHandler;)V
   at com.thaiopensource.relaxng.input.parse.sax.SAXParseInputFormat.makeParseable(SAXParseInputFormat.java:25)
   at com.thaiopensource.relaxng.input.parse.ParseInputFormat.load(ParseInputFormat.java:40)
   at com.thaiopensource.relaxng.translate.Driver.run(Driver.java:135)
   at com.thaiopensource.relaxng.translate.Driver.main(Driver.java:44)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [Trang](http://www.thaiopensource.com/relaxng/trang.html)? (I don't know how it deals with inheritance)

See also [xsd to rnc (or rng) conversion (unix command line)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122089/xsd-to-rnc-or-rng-conversion-unix-command-line) for a general discussion on converting XSD to RELAXNG. It looks like the Sun RELAX NG Converter goes under the name rngconv, and still hides out in certain places: http://rpm.pbone.net/index.php3?stat=3&search=msv-rngconv&srodzaj=3

Comment: One problem with suggesting Trang is that it does not accept XSD input.

Comment: @Rintze, yes, I've tried - but it is like Sperberg writes - unfortunately, it does not accept xsd as input - just as output. I've misread it the first time, too.